# Java collections maintaining insertion order

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

Why do some collection data structures not maintain the order of insertion?  What is the special thing achieved compared to maintaining order of insertion?
Do we gain something if we don't maintain the order?

Comment: For instance, Why does a `java.util.HashSet` need to maintain order of insertion?

Comment: no ..  i am asking ..does we loose anything while maintaining order ..contrary do we gain something if we doesn't maintain the order

Comment: eg:LinkedList. Think about it, wouldn't it be easier to append/prepend to a linked list than insert it in the middle?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Performance. If you want the original insertion order there are the `LinkedXXX` classes, which maintain an additional linked list in insertion order. Most of the time you don't care, so you use a `HashXXX`, or you want a natural order, so you use `TreeXXX.` In either of those cases why should you pay the extra cost of the linked list?

Comment: Where does `ArrayList` fit in the answer?

Comment: @ADTC It doesn't fit in the answer.

Comment: Well, ArrayList maintains insertion order with array backing, but I suppose the performance is worse than LinkedXXX classes?

Comment: @ADTC It maintains insertion order if you don't use the indexed insertion methods, or sort it, and so does LinkedList. 'With array backing ' is irrelevant. The performance in both cases is described in the Javadoc.

Answer (score 20):

The collections don't maintain order of insertion. Some just default to add a new value at the end. Maintaining order of insertion is only useful if you prioritize the objects by it or use it to sort objects in some way.

As for why some collections maintain it by default and others don't, this is mostly caused by the implementation and only sometimes part of the collections definition.

- **Lists** maintain insertion order as just adding a new entry at the end or the beginning is the fastest implementation of the add(Object ) method.
- **Sets** The HashSet and TreeSet implementations don't maintain insertion order as the objects are sorted for fast lookup and maintaining insertion order would require additional memory. This results in a performance gain since insertion order is almost never interesting for Sets.
- **ArrayDeque** a deque can used for simple que and stack so you want to have ''first in first out'' or ''first in last out'' behaviour, both require that the ArrayDeque maintains insertion order. In this case the insertion order is maintained as a central part of the classes contract.

Answer (score 7):

- The insertion order is inherently not maintained  in [hash tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashtable) - that's just how they work (read the linked-to article to understand the details). It's possible to add logic to maintain the insertion order (as in the `LinkedHashMap`), but that takes more code, and at runtime more memory and more time. The performance loss is usually not significant, but it can be.
- For `TreeSet/Map`, the main reason to use them is the natural iteration order and other functionality added in the `SortedSet/Map` interface.

Comment: Just on a quick side note: strictly speaking `Map` implementations are not `Collection`s as they do not implement the `Collection` interface. They do have similar methods, but that's it. Check: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/collections/overview.html (#Collection Interfaces) Most likely the OP's question addresses maps too though.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you need the implementation to do well.  Insertion order usually is not interesting so there is no need to maintain it so you can rearrange to get better performance.

For Maps it is usually HashMap and TreeMap that is used.  By using hash codes, the entries can be put in small groups easy to search in.  The TreeMap maintains a sorted order of the inserted entries at the cost of slower search, but easier to sort than a HashMap.

Answer (score 2):

When you use a HashSet (or a HashMap) data are stored in "buckets" based on the hash of your object. This way your data is easier to access because you don't have to look for this particular data in the whole Set, you just have to look in the right bucket.

This way you can increase performances on specific points.

Each Collection implementation have its particularity to make it better to use in a certain condition. Each of those particularities have a cost. So if you don't really need it (for example the insertion order) you better use an implementation which doesn't offer it and fits better to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Why is it necessary to maintain the order of insertion? If you use `HashMap`, you can get the entry by `key`. It does not mean it does not provide classes that do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Theres's a section in the O'Reilly Java Cookbook called "Avoiding the urge to sort"  The question you should be asking is actually the opposite of your original question ... "Do we gain something by sorting?"  It take a lot of effort to sort and maintain that order.  Sure sorting is easy but it usually doesn't scale in most programs.  If you're going to be handling thousands or tens of thousands of requests (insrt,del,get,etc) per second whether not you're using a sorted or non sorted data structure is seriously going to matter.

Answer (score 0):

Okay ... so these posts are old as compared to now, but insertion order is needed depending on your need or application requirements, so just use the right type of collection. For most part, it is not needed, but in a situation where you need to utilize objects in the order they were stored, I see a definite need. I think order matters when you are creating for instance a wizard or a flow engine or something of that nature where you need to go from state to state or something. In that sense you can read off stuff from the list without having it keep track of what you need next or traverse a list to find what you want. It does help with performance in that sense. It does matter or else these collections would not make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

some Collection are not maintain the order because of, they calculate the hashCode of content and store it accordingly in the appropriate bucket.

Answer (score -1):

I can't  cite a reference, but by design the `List` and `Set` implementations of the `Collection` interface are basically extendable `Array`s. As `Collections` by default offer methods to dynamically *add* and *remove* elements at any point -- which `Array`s don't -- insertion order might not be preserved. 
Thus, as there are more methods for content manipulation, there is a need for special implementations that do preserve order.

Another point is performance, as the most well performing `Collection` might not be that, which preserves its insertion order. I'm however not sure, how exactly `Collections` manage their content for performance increases.

So, in short, the two major reasons I can think of why there are order-preserving `Collection` implementations are:

1. Class architecture
2. Performance

Comment: Note that `Arrays` is an actual class, while arrays are a special type of container objects. I'm also pretty sure `LinkedList` actually does use a linked list but I haven't read the code. :-)

Comment: Ok, point taken, I edited my post. About your `LinkedList` comment: where is the contradiction to what I posted?

Comment: To clarify: A `LinkedList` afaik is a `List` (read extendable `Array`) whose insertion order is maintained in another `List` (the two of which are *linked*, hence the name). Or, am I wrong on that one?

Comment: A very confused and confusing post. A LinkedList is not an extensible array, and neither is a List: it depends on the implementation. Neither of them contains 'another List'. I don't know what you mean by 'which Arrays don't.' Your second paragraph is basically meaningless. Your conclusions don't follow from your premisses.

Comment: Spiteful, are we? I'm not drawing conclusions and there can't be anything confusing about asking a question unless you don't understand it.

Comment: Also, the `Array` object does not offer methods to dynamically remove and add elements. That's why `List` exists in the first place. My second paragraph says what you say in your post. Don't flame away on your first impression, buddy.

Comment: 'So' introduces your conclusion. You didn't ask a question. There is no 'Array object'. There is an ArrayList class which *does* offer those methods. My other statements remain true.