# Struts 2 iterator Tag

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have a collection of Java Beans which I want to iterate in the JSP using iterator tag.

What is the default order in which the list is sorted by this tag?
Because it does not iterate in the order in which the beans were added in the list.

This is the struts action class code:

```
public String getUsersTraceJSP() {

    try {

        Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(properties);
        PartnerSessionBeanRemote bIRemote = (PartnerSessionBeanRemote) ic.lookup(PartnerSessionBeanRemote.class.getName());

        UserLoginTraceForm ultf = bIRemote.getUserLoginTrace(Long.parseLong(userId));

        for (UserLoginTraceForm uu : ultf.getUltList()) {
            System.out.println("ULT ID | " + uu.getUltId());
        }

        session.put("ULTF", ultf);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Logger.printError("ERROR", "AppFilesAction.getUsersTraceJSP() ", e);
    }

    return "success";
}
```

`System.out.println("ULT ID | " + uu.getUltId())` gives this output:

```
INFO:   ULT ID | 91
INFO:   ULT ID | 9
INFO:   ULT ID | 86
INFO:   ULT ID | 84
INFO:   ULT ID | 83
INFO:   ULT ID | 82
INFO:   ULT ID | 81
INFO:   ULT ID | 8
INFO:   ULT ID | 74
INFO:   ULT ID | 73
INFO:   ULT ID | 72
INFO:   ULT ID | 71
INFO:   ULT ID | 70
INFO:   ULT ID | 7
INFO:   ULT ID | 69
INFO:   ULT ID | 68
INFO:   ULT ID | 67
INFO:   ULT ID | 66
INFO:   ULT ID | 65
INFO:   ULT ID | 64
INFO:   ULT ID | 63
INFO:   ULT ID | 62
INFO:   ULT ID | 61
INFO:   ULT ID | 6
INFO:   ULT ID | 5
INFO:   ULT ID | 49
INFO:   ULT ID | 48
INFO:   ULT ID | 47
INFO:   ULT ID | 46
INFO:   ULT ID | 45
INFO:   ULT ID | 44
INFO:   ULT ID | 43
INFO:   ULT ID | 42
INFO:   ULT ID | 41
INFO:   ULT ID | 40
INFO:   ULT ID | 4
INFO:   ULT ID | 39
INFO:   ULT ID | 38
INFO:   ULT ID | 37
INFO:   ULT ID | 36
INFO:   ULT ID | 35
INFO:   ULT ID | 34
INFO:   ULT ID | 33
INFO:   ULT ID | 32
INFO:   ULT ID | 31
INFO:   ULT ID | 30
```

And the JSP Is:

and the Output is This:
[image: List View on JSP]

```
<div class="row" style="height:92.5%;padding-left: 1%;padding-right: 1%;overflow: auto">
    <div id="tableDiv" >

        <table id="formList" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead style="background-color: #BDC6E7">
                <tr>
                    <th>ultId>
                    <th>Login Time</th>
                    <th>IP Address</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>


                <s:iterator value="#session.ULTF.ultList">
                    <tr>

                        <td><s:property value="ultId"/></td>
                        <td><s:property value="loginTime"/></td>
                        <td><s:property value="ipAddress"/></td>                 

                    </tr>
                </s:iterator>
            </tbody>
        </table>



    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: The "default order" is whatever order the list iterates in.

Comment: Now the Problem is that the order displayed in println is different and in the view the order is in increasing order of ULT_ID

Comment: That is the case of *A picture is worth a thousand words*. :) You have some datagrid.

Comment: Exactly, your grid is reordering the stuff, there is also an arrow up telling you data is ordered by ultld asc...

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem. The Datagrid API reordered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a `Collection` that preserves the insertion order of its elements, then use a `List`, that is intrisically ordered, or a class starting with `Linked`, like `LinkedHashSet`, `LinkedHashMap`, etc... that is *exactly* what makes them different from the other implementations. Read more on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3694168/1654265).

Comment: I know about List property that it iterates in the order the elements are inserted in. But Struts 2 iterator tag seems to do iteration differently.