# Insertion order maintenance need in Java Collections

Tags: java, collections

I tried to browse docs and stack overflow but couldn't figure out the specific needs in real life programming to maintain insertion order. I went through, [Java collections maintaining insertion order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694159/java-collections-maintaining-insertion-order) but that doesn't answer my curiosity either.

I mean, I have seen various code bases and programming from past few years and have not seen folks using `LinkedHashSet`  while `HashSet` and `TreeSet` are very popular and same is the case with `LinkedHashMap`. So is maintaining insertion order really a rare need? I know the difference among `LinkedHashSet,HashSet,` and `TreeSet` but wondering as why usage of `LinkedHashSet` or  `LinkedHashMap` so rare?

I might be incorrect about my assessment about usage rarity of LinkedHashSet & LinkedHashMap but that is what I have seen in projects that I executed in last few years (Banking and HealthCare projects). Through this question, I also wish to validate if my observation is correct / incorrect about LinkedHashSet & LinkedHashMap or need to maintain insertion order in general (that there are very rare cases when we really need insertion order while using Java Collections Framework).

Comment: Interesting question.. I think one of the use case may be where we need to store tokens some where and these tokens are than used in FIFO order.

Comment: I guess in most cases you need only either in-order access or direct access but not both. In the first case you would use a `List`.

Comment: This is an interesting, valid question, but not one that really seems to be a great fit for Stack Overflow's model of having questions that can have specific, concrete answers.  I'm voting to close it on those grounds.

Answer (score 2):

One use of LinkedHashMap that I have seen is in LRU cache.
P.S. wanted to comment but couldn't due to low reputation.