# Java, printing arraylist in alphabetical order in ToString with compareTo method

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to print the persons in the arraylist "medewerkers" (employees in english) in alphabetical order.

I've made a compareTo method to get them in alphabetical order, this method is set in an abstract class called "Persoon" (person in english). I want to print the ToString method of class "Bedrijf", this has to print the names in the arraylist in alphabetical order. But I can't figure out how to do it.

The structure of my program:

I have a class "Bedrijf"(company in English) where all employees of the company are set in an arraylist. I also have an abstract class "Persoon" (person in english), because a company has persons. Then there are several other classes that extend "Persoon" in these classes i define different functions such as manager, normal employee (Werknemer in my program) and several more.
Now all these persons are set in an arraylist in the class "Bedrijf" and I want to print all the names I've set in the arraylist in alphabetical order.

My Main class where I add people to the lisy through the "neemInDienst" method from Bedrijf:

```
public class Main {

    /**
     * The entry point of application.
     *
     * @param args the input arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Bedrijf bedrijf = new Bedrijf("HvA");

        Werknemer w = new Werknemer(1200.00, "Jantine Jansen");
        bedrijf.neemInDienst(w);

        Werknemer we = new Werknemer(1300.00, "Piet Pietersen");
        bedrijf.neemInDienst(we);

        Vrijwilliger v = new Vrijwilliger("Guus Goedhart");
        bedrijf.neemInDienst(v);
        v.huurIn(10);

        Manager m = new Manager(10000.00, "Brigitte Baas");
        bedrijf.neemInDienst(m);
        m.kenBonusToe(750);

        Manager a = new Manager(10000.00, "Dirk Teur");
        bedrijf.neemInDienst(a);
        a.kenBonusToe(1200);

        Zzper z = new Zzper(120, "Beun Haas");
        bedrijf.neemInDienst(z);
        z.huurIn(40);

        // print de toString van het bedrijf
        System.out.println(bedrijf);

        // print alle inkomsten van de personen in het bedrijf (alle functies)
        bedrijf.printInkomsten();

        // print de aantal van de managers
        System.out.println("\nAantal in management: " + bedrijf.aantalManagers());
    }

}
```

Class Bedrijf where the arraylist is and the one I want to print:

```
public class Bedrijf {
    private String naam;


    /**
     * lijst van alle Medewerkers.
     */
    protected List<Persoon> medewerkers = new ArrayList<>();

    //Magic numbers
    static private int MIN_MANAGERS = 0;


    /**
     * Instantiates a new Bedrijf.
     *
     * @param naam the naam
     */
    public Bedrijf(String naam) {
        this.naam = naam;
    }

    /**
     * Print inkomsten.
     *
     */
    public void printInkomsten() {
        System.out.println("Inkomsten van alle personen:\n");


        for (Persoon p : medewerkers) {
            if (p.berekenInkomsten() == 0) {
                System.out.println(p.naam + "," + " bedankt voor uw inzet!"); // Voor de vrijwilligers
            } else {
                System.out.println(p.naam + "," + " inkomsten: " + p.berekenInkomsten()); // Voor alle andere personen
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Aantal managers int.
     *
     * @return the int
     */
    public int aantalManagers() {
        int managers = MIN_MANAGERS;
        for (Persoon person : medewerkers) {
            if (person instanceof Manager) {
                managers++;
            }
        }
        return managers;
    }

    /**
     * Neemin dienst.
     *
     * @param persoon the persoon
     */
    public void neemInDienst(Persoon persoon) {
        this.medewerkers.add(persoon);

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String a = "Bedrijf " + naam + " heeft " + medewerkers.size() + " mederwerkers:\n";
        StringBuilder namen = new StringBuilder();
        for (Persoon x : medewerkers) {
            namen.append(x.naam).append("\n");
        }

        return a + namen;
    }


}
```

The abstract class "Persoon"

```
public abstract class Persoon implements Comparable<Persoon> {
    String naam;

    /**
     * Instantiates a new Persoon.
     *
     * @param naam the naam
     */
    public Persoon(String naam) {
        this.naam = naam;
    }

    /**
     * Bereken inkomsten.
     *
     * @return the double
     */
    public abstract Double berekenInkomsten();

    /**
     * compareto method om int terug te geven voor alfabetische volgorde
     *
     * @param other
     * @return laagste int is eerste in de alfabetische volgorde
     */
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Persoon other){
        return this.naam.compareTo(other.naam);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.naam;
    }
}
```

Maybe if it's easier to read the functions it's about:

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        String a = "Bedrijf " + naam + " heeft " + medewerkers.size() + " mederwerkers:\n";
        StringBuilder namen = new StringBuilder();
        for (Persoon x : medewerkers) {
            namen.append(x.naam).append("\n");
        }

        return a + namen;
    }
```

I'm fairly new to Java so if someone could help that'll be great!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Collections.sort()... allows you to sort a collection that isn't automatically updated on insert. But Q/As here might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694159/java-collections-maintaining-insertion-order

Comment: https://code.sololearn.com/c8Aj9LlPkqGW/#java - this would allow you to maintain sort on insert to a collection with a TreeSet (TreeSets can't contain duplicates/null values). More of a summary of collections here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/overview.html

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem by the help of the comments.

Added:

```
Collections.sort(medewerkers)
```

in the to string method, before looping through the list to print all the names in alphabetic order.